# Hibernate transactions and JTA

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

So I was reviewing a legacy project I was involved in a couple of years ago. And I noticed something that has been bugging me for a couple of days. This application used two different filters for transaction handling. One filter called **HibernateFilter** and another called **TransactionFilter** (see code below).

**My question is:** *why use the second TransactionFilter? Isn't the HibernateFilter enough?*

I hope someone here can explain this or if there is something I'm missing.

**HibernateFilter:**

```
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                       ServletResponse response,
                       FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED) == null) {
      request.setAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED, FILTER_APPLIED);
      applyFilter(request, response, chain);
    } else {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }

  private void applyFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException {
    try {
      if (sf == null) {
        log.info("SessionFactory assigned from XMLConfig!");
        sf = XMLConfig.getSessionFactory();
      }
      log.debug("Starting a database transaction");
      sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

      // Call the next filter (continue request processing)
      chain.doFilter(request, response);

      // Commit and cleanup
      log.debug("Committing the database transaction");
      sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("HibernateFilter, intressting error: " + getRequestUrl(request) + " " + ex, ex);
      // Rollback only
      try {
        log.debug("Trying to rollback database transaction after exception");
        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
      } catch (Throwable rbEx) {
        log.error("Could not rollback transaction after exception!", rbEx);
      }

      // Let others handle it... maybe another interceptor for exceptions?
      throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
  }
```

**TransactionFilter:**

```
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Boot the session!!!
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(this.getClass().getName(),"Session forced to start!");

    // Start orion transaction...
    Object attribute = servletRequest.getAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED);
    if (attribute == null) {
      servletRequest.setAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED, FILTER_APPLIED);
      applyFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
    } else {// Skip filter if run more than once for a request.
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

  }

  private void applyFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException {
    TransactionManager manager = null;
    try {
      manager = (TransactionManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
      if (manager != null) {
        manager.begin();
      }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      LOG.error("Cant find TransactionManager!", e);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
      LOG.error("Error starting transaction!", e);
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
      LOG.error("begin() not supported!", e);
    }
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
      if (manager != null) {
        manager.commit();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      try {
        if (manager != null) {
          manager.rollback();
          // Let others handle the rest... maybe another interceptor for exceptions?
          throw new ServletException(e);
        }
      } catch (SystemException e1) {
        LOG.error("Couldn't rollback!", e1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: As I understand it right, the first one handles the database transaction regardless off any user session over low level hibernate apis. And the second one forces a user session for every request which gets started and commited on start and end. Regarding on the envorinment this is running the second one should cause the same behavior as the first one did, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options why this was done, most of them are just nobody was knowing it better at that time.

But at least I can give you a scenario where this partially makes sense. But before I do this some hibernate / JPA / JTA fundamentals.

1. **Hibernate** and especially the **SessionFactory** is a hibernate only mechanic not part of a java standard. This is what your team was using for the hibernate related interactions.
2. **JPA** is the java standard regarding **Object Relational Mapping**, it was for the most part inspired by hibernate. More common in combination with JPA is the **EntityManager** and **EntityManagerFactory**. This can be used in combination with hibernate, since **Hibernate** is an **implementation** of the **standard**. For the most part you can start a transaction commit,... with either The Hibernate Session and the EntityManager.
3. **JTA** is the **Java Transaction API**. This is simply a standard to process transactions in an application. The @Transactional annotation is a part of this specification and is **often used in combination with a JPA implementation**. These two standards are designed to work well together. The usage of the transaction management from the EntityManager and the JTA specification at the same time is not possible (if I remember correctly). But beside the usage in combination with JPA, this specification is **not limited to JPA or Databases** at all. This standard can also be used to ensure transactional processing of **JMS resources**. Basically anything that implements the standard properly can be processed "transactional". Just see something as a DataSource whatever it is.

Lets come to the why it was used. I assume there's an application server in use where a data source is configured and process transactional. For example JMS resources. On the other hand they wanted to use hibernate as there persistence provider. And now there are different options why they did not use the JPA based datasource with hibernate as the persistence provider. One is that the application server had a bundled JPA implementation and the team was not able to overrule/replace it. Another one would be that they wanted to use hibernate custom features which are not part of the JPA specification and they were not able to combine this with the JPA way.

To sum it up, there are a plenty of options and my answer is a lot of guessing, but I hope it helps at least a bit.